# Unable to submit TestFlight build via Fastlane Pilot

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

After uploading an app and submitting it for review via `FastLlane deliver`, I'm trying to kick off internal testing via `pilot`. However, as soon as I do so with a command such as:

```
pilot distribute -a com.foo.bar.awesomesauce -u me@example.com -w test_test_test
```

I get the following error:

```
Error finding relevant GitHub issues: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

[!] The request could not be completed because:
    Beta App Description is required. The phone number is missing. The email must be in the format: contact@example.com. The email is required. Beta App Description is required. The email must be in the format: contact@example.com. The email is required. The phone number is missing. Validation errors
```

The exception is self-evident, and hopping into iTunes Connect evidently shows the issue: Data is not there.

I've pushed that metadata as part of my DeliverFile (first name, last name, email, phone, notes, ...), and I see it in the app version to be submitted for review, but I don't see it replicated in the metadata for the test build itself.

Is there a place I can set it? Right now through the command line in `pilot`, it looks like I can only set the "What's new." Anywhere in `deliver`? I've tried it through `spaceship` via `submit_for_beta_review` against the last build and passing all the parameters, but I still get a similar error.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Hey @napo - Have u fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2):

So based on this [discussion](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6011) on this exact same issue, you have a couple options it seems:

1) If this is the first time you're using `pilot`, then

> You'll need to fill out basic metadata in iTC before you can use pilot.

2) Otherwise, it seems

> You can use the *submission_information* in `deliver` to setup most of this.

I hope this resolves your issue with `fastlane pilot` :)

Comment: Well, filling this info manually defeats the purpose of automation right?